# Microsoft SQL Server. Не получается вывести Значения из Столбца 1 с наибольшим соответствием ему уникальных значений в Столбце 2

Tags: sql, sql-server

Необходима помощь! Что имеется?

1. Есть Товар в столбце Tovar и есть Цвет товара в столбце Cvet;
2. Количество разновидностей товаров и расцветок товаров может быть большим;
3. Много строк с одинаковым соответствием товара и цвета;

Не совсем получается создать запрос удовлетворяющий требованиям:
Необходимо вывести TOP товаров(отсортировать по убыванию), в которых присутствует наибольшее разнообразие(уникальность) расцветок.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ранее использовал указанный ниже код, но в результате значительного увеличения количества товара последующая ручная выборка стала требовать много времени да и задачи немного изменились, что и привело к необходимости решения вышеуказанной задачи.

```
SELECT Tovar, Cvet, count(Tovar) As col 
FROM tabl 
Group By Tovar, Cvet
HAVING count(Tovar) > 1
ORDER BY col desc
```

Comment: А что значит "не совсем получается", что вы уже пробовали сделать ? Вообще вам нужен group by, count(distinct x) и order by

Comment: подготовьте исходные данные в виде скрипта, а не картинки

Comment: Прежде чем сортировать по какому-то значению (в данном случае - по количеству цветов), неплохо бы это значение вообще посчитать...

Answer (score 0):

1. Считаем количество цветов у товара
2. Выводим максимальное

```
WITH cte (Tovar_cte, r_cte)
AS
(
SELECT
   Tovar,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Tovar Order BY Cvet) as r
FROM You_table
GROUP BY Tovar, Cvet
)
SELECT
   Tovar_cte as Tovar,
   MAX(r_cte) as 'count Cvet'
FROM cte
GROUP BY Tovar_cte
ORDER BY MAX(r_cte) DESC
```

Comment: значение синтаксиса цте и окошек, конечно, похвально, но но тут банальное `group by tovar order by count(distinct cvet) desc`.

Comment: @teran учту при подобных задачах, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  Tovar,
        COUNT(DISTINCT Cvet) AS CountCvet
FROM tabl
GROUP BY Tovar
ORDER BY CountCvet DESC
```